# How to treat users as Anonymous in Confidential Groups?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

Here is my problem.

- Mark an Organic Group as Confidential Group while creating it.
- Users will be asked with a question saying would you like to be Anonymous while joining Confidential Group.
- If user opted for Anonymous then all the content and activity inside group will be shown as Anonymous user as Author in front end but who posted details will be tracked in back end with user details. So, Technically Content Author is author of the node, but Author field should be shown as anonymous in front end !

This will be useful in Sensitive Groups where user identity should be hidden.

Any hooks or out of the box modules or solutions for above three problems ?

Answer (score 2):

I would add a "anonymous" field in the user account: admin/config/people/accounts/fields

then, in node pre-processing, do a check to see if the author of the node is anonymous and re-write the author field accordingly.